# Table of numbers less than $n$ of a certain type

Tags: list-manipulation, code-request

If I have a large number, for example,

```
2^11
```

is there code to list a table of positive integers less than this number which are *not* of the form

```
p^k *j
```

where $p$ is prime and $j\not=p$ is either prime or 1?

**Update**: The restriction

```
p^k * j < 2^11
```

forces (in case j=1)

```
p^k < 2^11
```

for each given p. So for each $p$, the largest $k$ (let's denote it $k_p$) for which $p^{k_p}<2^{11}$ is $k_p=$

```
Floor[11 Log[2] / Log[p]]
```

Comment: Any conditions on `k`?

Comment: k can only be so large so that the product is less than    2^11. I'll edit the post.

Comment: does this give what you need: `Pick[#, Not[PrimeQ[FactorInteger[#, 2][[-1, 1]]]] & /@ #] &@
 Range[2^11]`?

Comment: @kglr I don't think so. When I try a smaller number, such as $2^6$, I obtain output     {1, 30, 60}, but 2*3*7=42 should also be in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
max = 2^11;

ps = Prime[Range[PrimePi[max - 1]]];
ks = Range /@ Floor[Log[ps, N[max - 1]]];
js = # /. (# -> Append[ps[[;; First[FirstPosition[ps, n_ /; n > #, -1,
          {1}]]]], 1] & /@ DeleteDuplicates[#]) &[Floor[(max - 1) ps^-1]];

Complement[Range[max - 1], Flatten[MapThread[Outer[Times, #, #2] &, {ps^ks, js}]]]
```

> {1, 30, 36, 42, 60, 66, 70, 72, 78, 84, 90, 100, 102, 105, 108, 110 .......

1 is included because i didn't use $k=0$. If thats wrong it should be `ks = Range[0, #]& /@ Floor[Log[ps, N[max - 1]]];`

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, then the form you describe can be tested with the following function:

```
PKJFormQ[k_Integer] := With[
  {factors = FactorInteger[k]},
  And[
    Length[factors] <= 2,
    Length@Cases[factors[[All, 2]], Except[1], {1}] <= 1]];
SetAttributes[PKJFormQ, Listable];
```

(I.e., there are at most 2 prime factors and either one or both of the prime factors has an exponent of 1.) You can then use any number of given Mathematica tools (like `Pick` or `Reap`) to do the rest; here are a couple examples on the limited range of up to `2^6`:

```
First@Last@Reap@Do[If[!PKJFormQ[k], Sow[k]], {k, 2^6}]
```

> {30, 36, 42, 60}

```
Pick[#, PKJFormQ[#], False]&@Range[2^6]
```

> {30, 36, 42, 60}

The full list is a bit long for `2^11`, so I won't paste it here, but it takes no time to run:

```
Length@Pick[#, PKJFormQ[#], False]&@Range[2^11]
```

> 773

Comment: I think 36 = 2*2*3*3 is missing, because there is two factors with multiplicity >1

Comment: Thanks; good catch! Was because `Complement` eliminated identical coefficients; now fixed.